# how to use kibana search field with special character "-"

Tags: search, elasticsearch, kibana

my ES index documents are nginx log data like :

```
    {
      "_index": "nginx-2017-04-30",
      "_type": "access",
      "_id": "AVu8nYNM_NKHiROBoHkE",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "cookie_logintoken": "-",
        "request_time": "0.000",
        "request": "POST /login/getMobileLoginCode HTTP/1.1",
        "http_protocol": "https",
        "request_id": "a6fb53fcf28b7d6b400f0611ac697f0d",
        "@timestamp": "2017-04-30T10:08:11+08:00",
        "http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)",
        "http_x_forwarded_for": "-",
        "request_uri": "/login/getMobileLoginCode",
        "remote_addr": "xxxxxxx",
        "http_ver": "-",
        "status": "503",
        "request_method": "POST",
        "hostname": "master",
        "request_body": "-",
        "upstream_response_time": "-",
        "http_vm": "-",   # my custom http header
        "remote_user": "-",
        "http_referer": "-"
      },
      "fields": {
        "@timestamp": [
          1493518091000
        ]
      },
      "sort": [
        1493518091000
      ]
    }
```

I want to use kibana to search all the `http_vm(my custom http header)` where the value is `"-"`.

I try to input search query but fail, kibana returns the empty result.

my search query :

```
http_vm:"-"
http_vm:"\\-"
http_vm:\\-
http_vm:(\\-)
```

How can i search the "-" field ?

thanks to @logan rakai, I find the way.

> Which version of ES are you running? Most likely your http_vm field is being analyzed by the standard analyzer which removes punctuations. In ES 5 there is the keyword sub field which is not analyzed. In earlier versions you can change the index mapping to have the field not_analyzed. – logan rakai

### SOLUTION:

this query worked:

**http_vm.keyword:"-"**

Comment: Which version of ES are you running? Most likely your http_vm field is being analyzed by the standard analyzer which removes punctuations. In ES 5 there is the keyword sub field which is not analyzed. In earlier versions you can change the index mapping to have the field not_analyzed.

Comment: my ES version is 5.2.2 ，I try http_vm.keyword:"-" ， worked!  thank you!